# OS X 10.10: Errors in locating and using brew and Git

Tags: git, macos, path, homebrew

Last time when I was using brew and Git, which was a couple of weeks ago, everything was working perfectly fine. Now, however, when I type `git --version` in the terminal I get

```
git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH.
```

I do have a Git folder in my /usr/local directory though ...

If I try `brew update`, I get the very same error, plus

```
Error: Failure while executing: git init.
```

`brew install git` results in:

```
clang: error: unable to find utility "clang", not a developer tool or in PATH
otool: error: unable to find utility "otool", not a developer tool or in PATH
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool
```

So, apparently, something is seriously wrong with my Git (and brew?) Installation or at least its path.

If I provide the path manually by entering

```
export PATH=/usr/local/git/bin:$PATH
```

in the terminal and then ask for my Git version, I get the correct output:

> git version 2.3.5

Can someone tell me what's going wrong here or how I can fix my path for Git and brew in order to work again?

Comment: This might be related to a recent update in the OS X command line tools.

Comment: Yes, there have been a quite a few updates for Xcode and the Command Line Tools recently. But as mentioned below I was already able to fix git by adding its location to my PATH. Now I need to fix brew/otool too ...

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` say?

Comment: /usr/local/git/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin ... Weird thing is that the path to git seems to be in there twice. The one at the end is the one I added a couple of minutes ago and that made git working. Be that as it may, now it's about otool. What do I need to add?

Comment: Your PATH looks okay. Have you moved Xcode by any chance? What does `xcode-select -p` say?

Comment: No, I haven't tampered with Xcode in any way. Just installed the updates that were released by Apple in the past couple of weeks. The ouput of the command you mention is "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"

Comment: Have you tried If `xcodebuild` command work as expected and If you have any XCode Plugins in the plugins Folder located at `~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins` who can cause this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OMG, I figured it all out! There is one thing I did two weeks ago: I installed Python 3.4 and uninstalled Python 2.7 that is preinstalled on OS X. And just now I found out that Python 2.7 is vital for Xcode, so I simply installed it again.

Now that both Python versions are on my system, not only does Xcode work without complaint again but brew doesn't produce any errors anymore either ...